# how to find all links at the same depth with a common closest ancestor with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, dom, nokogiri

```
d=<<"EOM"
<ul>
  <li><a id=t href="t">a</a></li>
  <li><a id=b href="b">b</a></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="inner">don't want inner</a></li>
      <li><a href="inner">don't want inner</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a id=c href="c">c</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="d">don't want</a></li>
</ul>
EOM

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(d)
t = doc.css("#t")[0]
```

how can i get all hrefs that have the same 
outer container as "t" and are at the same
*depth* as "t"?  in this case i'd want just the
hrefs t,b,c.
these will not always be in ul's, just using
it as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all a tags with the same 'grandparent' as t you could do:

```
doc.css('a').select{|a| a.parent.parent == t.parent.parent}
```

To get their hrefs:

```
doc.css('a').select{|a| a.parent.parent == t.parent.parent}.map{|a| a[:href]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IDs will be consistent:

```
puts doc.search('#t, #b, #c').map{ |n| n['href'] }
```

If you don't know what they would be, then XPath can get you there:

```
doc.search('//*[@id="t"]/../../*/*[@id]').to_html
=> "<a id=\"t\" href=\"t\">a</a><a id=\"b\" href=\"b\">b</a><a id=\"c\" href=\"c\">c</a>"

doc.search('//*[@id="t"]/../../*/*[@id]').map{ |n| n['href'] }
=> ["t", "b", "c"]
```

That means "find the node with an ID of 't', then back up two levels and look down finding the nodes with populated id attributes".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pguardiario

The parent node could be at any level, so I modified your code like so:

```
 t = doc.css("#a")[0]
 r = []
 p = t.parent
 x = 0
 while true
   break if p.node_name == "body" || p.node_name == "html"
   x += 1
   r = doc.css('a').select{|a| 
     m = a
     x.times { m = m.parent }
     m  == p
     } 
   break if r.length > 1
   p = p.parent
 end
 pp r.length
```

I'm sure there's a better way than this brute force method.